# CSS border radius is not curving the same on all side of the box

Tags: css

could anyone tell me why, if i use border-radius: 10px it doesn't round all the edges the same?

```
#portfolio1
{

    background-image:url("images/bg.png");
    background-repeat: none;

    height: 150px;

    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;  
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;*/
    /*-webkit-border-radius: 20px;*/
}
```

Notice I've commented a few lines of css where I was trying different things. I seems that if I to the individual border values to different for left and right edges it looks okay but still has something wrong with it.

Also the same with the webkit one. I'm using chrome, did try it with firefox as well but got the same problem. Could it be to do with the margin values I'm using? also I have portfolio1, portfolio2 and portfolio3 which are all very similar, but when displayed on my webpage I'm using each of them twice..... If that makes a difference.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tested http://jsfiddle.net/cwVez/. Seems to look the same on all sides (I added a bg color, as I haven't your image.)  Any way we can see the err you have?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wQFZb/ - for me all borders look the same

Comment: The CSS you've supplied works perfectly for me, so it's probably a conflict when you have it live. Do you have a link? Also, if portfolio1, portfolio2 and portfolio3 are all styled using `id`'s, then they must be unique on the page. Use a `class` instead.

Comment: Okay, i tested it with and without a background image... for some reason, without the image it works fine, but when i add the background  the bend on the left top and bottom aren't like the ones of the right. I'm trying to upload an image but its not working well at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to make all the edges round at 10px then you don't need to have it be so complicated (specifying topright,topleft,etc.)

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

[Here's a very useful tool you can use.](http://border-radius.com/)